# How to assign a default parameter to a function aside of map parameter in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Any idea how to assign a default parameter to a function aside of `Map` parameter in dart?

```
static Future functionName(
  bool isDone,
  [
    Map<String, String> params,
  ]
) async {
    ....
}
```

Note that if I put `functionName([...],{bool isDone = false})` it doesn't work until I remove `[...],`

Comment: Why can't the parameters of the method be functionName(Map<String, String> params, {bool isDone = false})?

Comment: because i have already lots of code calling this function in this format, and i can't reformat the function to avoid the big impact on my code!

Comment: Then I would probably create a new method with new parameters that then call the old method. I'm not sure what you're asking is possible.

Comment: Yes most probably is not possible in dart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend helped me with this and figured out that function args can take default values have to be given inside [] or {}, so this is how we pass it:

```
static Future functionName(
  [
    Map<String, String> params,
    bool isDone = false,
  ]
) async {
    ....
}
```

And call it like this:

```
functionName(
  {
    'key1': value1,
    'key2': value2,
    ...
  },
  true,
);
```

Comment: This will not work the way you describe (`isDone` is not a named parameter), and it will require changing all existing callers, which in the comments you said that you didn't want to do.

Comment: I think you meant **isDone: true,** right? i corrected it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want `isDone` to have a default value, that means it will need to become an *optional* parameter.  Your function has an existing optional *positional* parameter (`params`), and [Dart currently does not allow mixing optional positional parameters with optional named parameters](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1076).  Therefore for `isDone` to be optional, it also must be positional.  To avoid breaking existing callers, it should remain the first parameter:

```dart
static Future functionName([
  bool isDone = false,
  Map<String, String>? params, // Remove the `?` if you don't enable null-safety.
]) async {
    ....
}
```

and then you would call it the same way that you already do:

```dart
functionName(
  true,
  {
    'key1': value1,
    'key2': value2,
    ...
  },
);
```

The only difference between this and your existing code is that you now will be able to call your function as just `functionName()`.  If you want callers to be able to call your function with `params` but *not* with `isDone`, then that would be a breaking change (you would need to update all callers) and would require reordering the parameters or changing the parameters to optional *named* parameters.